# How to replace variable in file_get_contents to generate css file with PHP?

Tags: php

I am developing my own cms with php and wanted to implement a color picker to change the color from the backend, but the problem is that i don't know how to generate the css with the new color value and when i open style.css the variables don't change.

What am i doing wrong? Is this the correct way to do it?

**generate.php**

```
$Color = "#000000";
$Background = "#555000";

$cssFile = file_get_contents('style.css');

$myfile = fopen("style.css", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $cssFile);
fclose($myfile);
```

**style.css**

```
#header {
    background-color: $Background;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
a {
    color: $Color;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a sample file: style.css.txt

```
#header {
    background-color: {php_background};
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
a {
    color: {php_color};
}
```

generate.php

```
<?php
/* -------------------- */
$color      = "#000000";
$background = "#555000";
/* -------------------- */
$cssFile = file_get_contents('style.css.txt');
/* -------------------- */
$cssFile = str_replace('{php_background}', $background, $cssFile);
$cssFile = str_replace('{php_color}', $color, $cssFile);
/* -------------------- */
$handler = fopen("style.css", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
/* -------------------- */
fwrite($handler, $cssFile);
fclose($handler);
/* -------------------- */
```

It will create new style.css file and insert the new color settings:

```
#header {
    background-color: #555000;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
a {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php string replace.. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$str=file_get_contents('style.css');
//replace something in the file string - this is a VERY simple example
$str=str_replace("color:blue;", "color:red",$str);
//write the entire string
file_put_contents('style.css', $str);
```